# NotifyDataSetChanged refreshes RecyclerView but scrolls as well.

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView and one item row needs to be updated like every second (SeekBar). So I call NotifyDataSetChanged once I update the data in the list. UI gets updated but the issue is that the RecyclerView scrolls so that this particular item is either at top or bottom of the screen.
I don't want RecyclerView to scroll.

```
// Update Data
    mData.set(mData.indexOf(cardData), cardData); 
    // RefreshView
    refreshView() {
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
          notifyDataSetChanged();
         }
     );
```

Comment: Can u post an image to clarify case?

Comment: Can you share the rest of your adapter please ?

Answer (score 1):

You can update one item using `notifyItemChanged(position);` and u wont update all data in adapter, you will update only certain item

Comment: Yes but that doesn't stop the scroll.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use the other notify methods from the RecyclerView.

For your usecase only swap out one item in your Adapter instead of all items and use [`notifyItemChanged(position)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int)).

This will be faster, the View won't scroll and if you ever will add an animation this will only work if you don't use `notifyDataSetChanged`

Comment: I have done that I am only updating the views that i need using other notify methods but the scroll still remains there.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I was having a card view above the recycler view.I just removed it. Now the whole screen is a recyclerView and I cannot see any auto scrolls.